# For - loop to execute on specific conditions

Tags: algorithm, for-loop

I have a for loop in which the limit of the count varies. For every 5 times the code runs through the loop it calls a METHOD and when left with few more times to run the loop say the loop is going to run for 3 more times and exits, I have to check on that value and then call the METHOD for the 3 times the code ran the loop.

Lets say n = 17

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
if(i%5){
  call method
 }
 // the remaining 2 more times the code run thru this loop i have to call the method

}
```

Any idea on how to deal with this situation?

Comment: Can you explain a little more this part  "when left with few more times to run the loop say the loop is going to run for 3 more times and exits, I have to check on that value and then call the METHOD for the 3 times the code ran the loop.". I did not understand you very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in a single condition.
The last i for which `(i%5 == 0)` is `5*(n/5)`.
Therefore you call the method when either `(i%5 == 0)` or `i > 5*(n/5)`.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
  if((i%5 == 0) || i > (5*(n/5))) {
    call method
  } 
}
```

In the example of n = 17, n/5 = 3, so you call the method for i = 0 , 5 , 10 & 15 and then the second part of the condition kicks in, and you call the method for i = 16 (note that there's only a `remaining 1 more time`, not 2, since the loop exits when i reaches 17).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
   if(i%5 == 0 || i > (n-3)) {
       //call method
   } 
}
```

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this should allow you to call the method every 5 times as well as the last three times through the loop.